# Convert big logfile to csv

Tags: csv, unix, command-line, cygwin

I have a big  text file withe the following structure (folders and files):

```
\FOLDER1\
    3/21/2012 2:23:56 PM               2,178                   100               Good        myfile1.txt
    3/21/2012 1:24:25 PM         253,928,960                   100               Good        myfile2.txt
    3/21/2012 1:24:51 PM               6,430                   100               Good        myfile3.txt
    3/21/2012 10:28:03 AM            206,796                   100               Good        myfile4.txt

\FOLDER2\SUBFOLDER\
    3/21/2012 10:47:03 AM              1,300                   100               Good        bla.txt
    3/21/2012 10:42:56 AM             76,226                   100               Good        xyz.txt
    3/21/2012 1:25:08 PM       5,911,839,232                   100               Good        kkkkkk.txt
    3/21/2012 10:33:33 AM              1,202                   100               Good        mmmmm.txt
    3/21/2012 10:33:16 AM          3,412,079                   100               Good        mmmmmd.txt
    3/21/2012 10:32:21 AM                812                   100               Good        fg.txt
    3/21/2012 10:33:44 AM              1,206                   100               Good        sss.txt
```

I need to parse the file and come up with a formated CSV (semicolon as column) divider:

```
\FOLDER1\;3/21/2012 2:23:56 PM;2,178;100;Good;myfile1.txt
...
\FOLDER2\SUBFOLDER\;3/21/2012 10:47:03 AM;1,300;100;Good;bla.txt
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/  */;/g' filename
```

will transform your file into:

```
\FOLDER1\
;3/21/2012;2:23:56;PM;2,178;100;Good;myfile1.txt
;3/21/2012;1:24:25;PM;253,928,960;100;Good;myfile2.txt
;3/21/2012;1:24:51;PM;6,430;100;Good;myfile3.txt
;3/21/2012;10:28:03;AM;206,796;100;Good;myfile4.txt
\FOLDER2\SUBFOLDER\
;3/21/2012;10:47:03;AM;1,300;100;Good;bla.txt
;3/21/2012;10:42:56;AM;76,226;100;Good;xyz.txt
;3/21/2012;1:25:08;PM;5,911,839,232;100;Good;kkkkkk.txt
;3/21/2012;10:33:33;AM;1,202;100;Good;mmmmm.txt
;3/21/2012;10:33:16;AM;3,412,079;100;Good;mmmmmd.txt
;3/21/2012;10:32:21;AM;812;100;Good;fg.txt
;3/21/2012;10:33:44;AM;1,206;100;Good;sss.txt
```

just to start with.

Then I think you will need to use perl or awk to make a loop and concatenate the folder until it changes.

Regards

Comment: Thank you, that is a good start indeed! Maybe someone could help with the awk loop as well  - sorry I am a greenhorn in that